# Composer - include from path that varies

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two applications, and I need one app to load the other app. I could just go

```
"files": [
  "/path/to/the/second/app"
],
```

in `composer.json` but the problem is that `/path/to/the/second/app` varies from server to server. The question is how can I load a file using composer if the file's path varies, but can be available in an env var or some config?

Comment: Oh I've just got an idea of using a symlink. Anyway I wonder if there are other solutions to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer doesn't support environment variables - https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2036

You could use a symlink that gets changed each time though

Comment: Thanks, a symlink perfectly suits me